# Get index number in ascending order for unique value in Power BI Query Editor

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

How to get values in **custom** column as shown below in Power BI Query Editor?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"PriorStepName", {"proj"}, {{"data", each  Table.AddIndexColumn(_, "Custom", 1, 1, Int64.Type) }})
```

then expand